# PostgreSQL Custom Login Message

Tags: postgresql

Does PostgreSQL allow you to set a login message when a user connects from a terminal?  I want to be able to present the user with some sort of warning along the lines of: "you are connecting to a database with confidential information".  I have searched for how to do this online, but I'm not having much luck. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Duplicate of this:  https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/251337/add-banner-motd-to-postgres-database

Comment: @MikeOrganek Thanks. Searching for banner instead of login or greeting is was what I was missing.